# how can Arrange rails params order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameters

when i look at my console after submitting a form i can see like

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"l0dqmb95MydzCWMugWdYt/2bGYyRyDF5ZfOGjrKhjfc=", "project_id"=>"second", "esthour"=>{"nonmodulhours_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"nonmodul_id"=>"61", "nonmodul_est_hours"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"nonmodul_id"=>"62", "nonmodul_est_hours"=>"9"}, "2"=>{"nonmodul_id"=>"63", "nonmodul_est_hours"=>""}}, "modul1hours_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"modul1_est_hours"=>"8", "modul1_id"=>"25"}, "1"=>{"modul1_est_hours"=>"", "modul1_id"=>"26"}**, "2"=>{"modul1_est_hours"=>"88", "modul1_id"=>"27"}}**, "ecommerce_est_hours"=>"", "modulhours_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"modul_est_hours"=>"8", "modul_id"=>"53"}, "1"=>{"modul_est_hours"=>"1", "modul_id"=>"54"}, "2"=>{"modul_est_hours"=>"8", "modul_id"=>"55"}}, "cms_est_hours"=>"", "nonmodul1hours_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"nonmodul1_id"=>"25", "nonmodul1_est_hours"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"nonmodul1_id"=>"26", "nonmodul1_est_hours"=>""}, "2"=>{"nonmodul1_id"=>"27", "nonmodul1_est_hours"=>"5"}}, "rfp_id"=>"35"}, "commit"=>"Add Todo", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

here how can i arrange  the attributes like line

```
 "2"=>{"modul1_est_hours"=>"88", "modul1_id"=>"27"}}
```

to

```
 "2"=>{ "modul1_id"=>"27","modul1_est_hours"=>"88",}}
```

****mean modul1_id before modul1_est_hours**

**form.html.erb****

```
<% @m1.map(&:id).each do |id|%>
```

```
 <%= modul1(id) %>  <%= f.hidden_field :modul1_id, :value => id %>

    <%= f.number_field :modul1_est_hours, :size => 30 %>
         </tr>
<% end %>
```

**Edit**

```
def get_issue_attribute_param1(u)
  u.each do |key, value|
    value.is_a?(Hash) ? get_issue_attribute_param1(value) : update_issue(key,value)
  end
end

def update_issue(q,p)
  if q.include?("_") 
    q1 = q.split("_")
    q0 = q1[0]

    if q1[0].include?("modul")  && q1[1] == "id"
      $id_map = p
      puts $id_map
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i want to get the ids first coz based on id, I need further updation..

Comment: fetching param value not depend on params order

Comment: Could you write this again, this time in English?

Comment: @Raj I agree but if there is any way then i need it

Comment: @Anish i think that need won't come...

Comment: `get_issue_attribute_param1(u)` here `u` is `params` ??

Comment: The order it totally irrelevant in a query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go(in irb):

```
a = {"modul1_est_hours"=>"88", "modul1_id"=>"27"}
 => {"modul1_est_hours"=>"88", "modul1_id"=>"27"} 
Hash[a.sort{|x,y| y.first <=> x.first }]
 => {"modul1_id"=>"27", "modul1_est_hours"=>"88"}
```

But, as everybody pointed out. If you could tell what you're trying to do, or what do you want with this? Then maybe what you're looking for maybe little more easy to understand and answer. :)

**Edit**

Here are the updated methods:

```
def get_issue_attribute_param1(params)
  ids = []
  params["esthour"].select{|hour| hour.include?('modul') }.each_pair do |key, value|
    ids << update_issue(value)
  end unless params["esthour"].nil?
  ids # will have array of array like this: [["61", "62", "63"], ["25", "26", "27"], ["53", "54", "55"], ["25", "26", "27"]] for which you can do: `.flatten`
end

def update_issue(id_with_hours)
  id_with_hours.values.map{|m| m.select{|v| v.include?('id') } }.map(&:values).flatten
end
```

Though I am not clear for what purpose you're using `$id_map` and hence I had to leave that scenario for you to handle. :)

I hope it helps.

Comment: send the params where? to another method in controller? or the intended method when submitting form?

Comment: to another method in controller

Comment: you can pass `params` to other method as well and then access the value(s) from the key(s). Why re-arranging the param? how will it help?

Comment: i need key, if it is id (as in this case) then i want to update based on next hours, hope you are clear

Comment: could you please post both the controller methods where you're trying to do this?